# InvalidArchiveError only on gxx_linux-64

Tags: python, conda

Recently, I am trying to install gxx on conda env.

```
conda install -c anaconda gxx_linux-64
```

However, it shows

```
Downloading and Extracting Packages
gxx_impl_linux-64-9. | 9.0 MB    | ####################################################################################### | 100%

InvalidArchiveError("Error with archive /maskedDir/.conda/pkgs/gxx_impl_linux-64-9.3.0-hbdd7822_17u43d5oig/pkg-gxx_impl_linux-64-9.3.0-hbdd7822_17.tar.zst.  You probably need to delete and re-download or re-create this file.  Message from libarchive was:\n\nCan't create 'x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/lib/libstdc++.*-gdb.py'")
```

I tried `conda clean -a`, it doesn't work. I also tried remove every gxx* on /MASKEDDir/.conda/pkgs. Not working also :(

I tried to install gcc_linux-64 and sklearn on the same env, it works. So I guess only gxx_linux-64 doesn't work. Any idea what to do?

Comment: Try installing one of the other builds (see [file list](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/gxx_impl_linux-64/files). It is strange that the latest builds have so few downloads - makes me think there is something awry in how they were packaged. Better, just use `conda-forge::compilers`.

Comment: Yup, you are right. It works when I try to install the previous build. Notice: The latest conda-forge::compilers seems to depend on the spoiled build, install previous conda-forge::compilers also solves the problem. Thanks

Comment: I wasn't able to recreate this. Just to double check: Are you sure you were deleting the correct package `gxx_impl_linux-64-9.3.0-hbdd7822_17`? Both the folder and the **.tar.gz** / **.conda** file?

Comment: I do `cd ~/.conda/pkgs` and `rm -rf gxx*`. It still shows the error InvalidArchiveError when I try to install gxx_impl_linux-64-9.3.0 [hbdd7822_17]. I can install gxx_impl_linux-64-7.3.0 [hdf63c60_1] tho. Do you mean you can install [hbdd7822_17]?

Comment: Yes, running on the latest Mambaforge Docker, installing `gxx_linux-64=9.3.0` also installed build `gxx_impl_linux-64=9.3.0=hbdd7822_17` with no errors.